# URIs for Standard Requests better ping response than CNAME Redirects

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am checking from India, BSNL home broadband connection, URIs for Standard Requests are getting excellent ping response always generally between 40 to 100ms

```
E:\Documents and Settings>ping storage.googleapis.com

Pinging storage-ugc.l.googleusercontent.com [74.125.236.106] with 32 bytes of da
ta:

Reply from 74.125.236.106: bytes=32 time=93ms TTL=56
Reply from 74.125.236.106: bytes=32 time=93ms TTL=56
Reply from 74.125.236.106: bytes=32 time=93ms TTL=56
Reply from 74.125.236.106: bytes=32 time=93ms TTL=56

Ping statistics for 74.125.236.106:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 93ms, Maximum = 93ms, Average = 93ms
```

whereas URI for CNAME Redirects is not getting similar ping response generally between 280 to 400 ms.

```
E:\Documents and Settings>ping c.storage.googleapis.com

Pinging storage.l.googleusercontent.com [74.125.135.128] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 74.125.135.128: bytes=32 time=315ms TTL=44
Reply from 74.125.135.128: bytes=32 time=296ms TTL=44
Reply from 74.125.135.128: bytes=32 time=312ms TTL=44
Reply from 74.125.135.128: bytes=32 time=312ms TTL=44

Ping statistics for 74.125.135.128:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 296ms, Maximum = 315ms, Average = 308ms
```

Is there any alternative URI for CNAME Redirects.